# Why do I get 'has unmet peer dependency' warning on CRA app?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, yarnpkg, prettier

On my CRA (Create-React-App) app, I think I have a right peer dependency "eslint" for dependencies showing below, but still get the warning on any command making changes in `node_modules`

[image]

`yarn.lock` shows that I have `eslint` specifically `7.32.0` which meets the version ranges of peer dependency that the warnings above say.
Does anyone have any idea why I still get these warnings?

[image]